# how to save spinner data and selected radio button saved to mysql database?

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

i cannot save selected radio buttons and spinner into mysql database? why is this?but for editText, it saves to my database.please help!
here is my submitData.php

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="submitData" method = "post">
        Gender <input type = "radio" name="gender" value ="<?php echo $row['Gender']?>">
                <input type = "radio" name="gender" value ="<?php echo $row['Gender']?>"
        </form>
    </body>
</html>

<?php

 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
 $Name = $_POST['Name'];
 $Age = $_POST['Age'];
 $Gender=$_POST['Gender'];
 $Email = $_POST['Email'];
 $Phone = $_POST['Phone'];
 $IncidentType = $_POST['IncidentType'];
 $Description = $_POST['Description'];

 require_once('dbConnect.php');

 $sql = "INSERT INTO user (Name,Age,Gender,Email,Phone,IncidentType,Description) VALUES ('$Name','$Age','$Gender','$Email','$Phone','$IncidentType','$Description')";


 if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
 echo "Successfully sent";
 }else{
 echo "Could not send";

 }
 }else{
echo 'error';
}
?>
```

here is my FormActivity.java:

```
public class FormActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener, AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    private static final String REGISTER_URL = "http://khaty-ismail0.rhcloud.com/phptutorial/submitData.php";
    private static final String SPINNER_URL = "http://khaty-ismail0.rhcloud.com/phptutorial/spinner_data.php";

    public static final String KEY_NAME= "Name";
    public static final String KEY_AGE = "Age";
    public static final String KEY_EMAIL = "Email";
    public static final String KEY_PHONE = "Phone";
    public static final String KEY_DESCRIPTION = "Description";
    public static final String KEY_TICKET = "ticket_id";
    public static final String KEY_SOLUTION = "solution";
    public static final String JSON_ARRAY = "result";

    private EditText name_eT;
    private EditText age_eT;
    private EditText email_eT;
    private EditText phone_eT;
    private EditText descr_eT;

    private Button subm_btn;
    private Spinner spinner;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_form);

        name_eT = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name_eT);
        age_eT = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.age_eT);
        email_eT= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email_eT);
        phone_eT= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phone_eT);
        descr_eT= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.descr_eT);

        subm_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.subm_btn);

        subm_btn.setOnClickListener(this);

        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), spinner.getSelectedItem().toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
    }
    private void registerUser(){
        final String Name = name_eT.getText().toString().trim();
        final String Age = age_eT.getText().toString().trim();
        final String Email = email_eT.getText().toString().trim();
        final String Phone = phone_eT.getText().toString().trim();
        final String Description = descr_eT.getText().toString().trim();

        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(Name)) {
            name_eT.setError("Please enter your name");
            return;
        }else if(TextUtils.isEmpty(Age)) {
            age_eT.setError("Please enter your age");
            return;
        }else if(TextUtils.isEmpty(Phone)) {
            phone_eT.setError("Please enter your phone");
            return;
        }else if(TextUtils.isEmpty(Email)) {
            email_eT.setError("Please enter your email");
            return;
        }else if(TextUtils.isEmpty(Description)) {
            descr_eT.setError("Please enter your issue");
            return;
        }
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, REGISTER_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Toast.makeText(FormActivity.this,response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(FormActivity.this,error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put(KEY_NAME,Name);
                params.put(KEY_AGE,Age);
                params.put(KEY_EMAIL, Email);
                params.put(KEY_PHONE, Phone);
                params.put(KEY_DESCRIPTION, Description);
                return params;
            }

        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
    public void onCheckboxClicked(View V) {

        boolean checked = ((RadioButton) V).isChecked();

        switch (V.getId()) {
            case R.id.male_rb:
                if (checked)

                    break;

            case R.id.female_rb:
                if (checked)

                    break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v == subm_btn){
            registerUser();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    }

    public void submitData(View view) {
        Intent getResponse =  new Intent(this,SubmitData.class);

        final int result = 1;

        startActivityForResult(getResponse, result);
    }
}
```

here is my activity_form.java:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@color/buttonFont"
    tools:context="com.example.khadijah.brucertv2.FormActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/User_info"
        android:id="@+id/userInfo"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorFont"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Name:"
        android:id="@+id/name_tV"
        android:textColor="@color/colorFont"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/userInfo"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/userInfo"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/userInfo" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Age:"
        android:id="@+id/age_tV"
        android:textColor="@color/colorFont"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/age_eT"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/name_tV"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/name_tV" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Gender"
        android:id="@+id/gender_tV"
        android:textColor="@color/colorFont"
        android:layout_below="@+id/age_tV"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/age_tV"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/age_tV"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Email:"
        android:id="@+id/email_tV"
        android:textColor="@color/colorFont"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/email_eT"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/name_tV"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/name_tV" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Phone"
        android:id="@+id/phone_tV"
        android:textColor="@color/colorFont"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/phone_eT"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/gender_tV"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/gender_tV" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:hint="@string/hint_required"
        android:textColorHint="@color/buttonFont"
        android:background="@drawable/border_style"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/name_eT"
        android:textColor="@color/inputFont"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/name_tV"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/userInfo"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/userInfo" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/hint_required"
        android:textColorHint="@color/buttonFont"
        android:background="@drawable/border_style"
        android:id="@+id/age_eT"
        android:textColor="@color/inputFont"
        android:layout_below="@+id/name_tV"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/userInfo"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/userInfo" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/email_eT"
        android:hint="@string/hint_required"
        android:textColorHint="@color/buttonFont"
        android:textColor="@color/inputFont"
        android:background="@drawable/border_style"
        android:layout_below="@+id/phone_eT"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/age_eT"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/age_eT" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/phone_eT"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:textColor="@color/inputFont"
        android:hint="@string/hint_required"
        android:textColorHint="@color/buttonFont"
        android:background="@drawable/border_style"
        android:layout_below="@+id/gender_tV"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/email_eT"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/email_eT" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/incident_info"
        android:id="@+id/incidentInfo"
        android:textColor="@color/colorFont"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:prompt="@array/incident_type"
        android:entries="@array/incident_type"
        android:layout_below="@+id/incidentInfo"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/phone_eT"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/phone_eT"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/phone_eT"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/phone_eT"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/incident_type_DD"
        android:textColor="@color/colorFont"
        android:id="@+id/incident_DD"
        android:layout_below="@+id/incidentInfo"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/spinner" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/description"
        android:id="@+id/description_tV"
        android:textColor="@color/colorFont"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/phone_tV"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/phone_tV" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/descr_eT"
        android:hint="@string/descr_hint"
        android:textColorHint="@color/buttonFont"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:background="@drawable/border_style"
        android:textColor="@color/inputFont"
        android:layout_below="@+id/description_tV"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/description_tV"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/description_tV" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:text="SUBMIT"
        android:onClick="submitData"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        android:id="@+id/subm_btn"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_btn"
        android:textColor="@color/buttonFont"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/phone_eT"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/phone_eT"
        android:layout_below="@+id/age_eT"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/descr_eT"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/descr_eT"
        android:layout_above="@+id/phone_eT"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup">

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="false"
            android:text="Male"
            android:id="@+id/male_rb"
            android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"/>
        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Female"
            android:checked="false"
            android:id="@+id/female_rb"
            android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"/>

    </RadioGroup>


</RelativeLayout>
```

here is my arrays.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string-array name="incident_type">
        <item>Fraud</item>
        <item>Malicious Code</item>
        <item>Spam</item>
        <item>Intrusion</item>
        <item>Not Sure</item>
    </string-array>


</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

the form name is case sensitive.
use $_POST['gender'];

another thing is. where is your definition of $row? looks like it may be empty so you will not post any data.

enable error_reporting and display_errors while development help you to find such kind of errors much faster

another thing very important dont use mysql_* functions they are insecure and deprecated. have a look ad PDO instead

also use prepared statements and escape userinput.

Comment: hi,i still cannot save the selected radio buttons for gender. is there any wrong with my php file above ?already update $_POST['gender'].

Comment: as said enable error reporting.. whats the value of <?php echo $row['Gender']?>

Comment: $row = mysql_fetch_array...but i dont know how to write the php..any help?please..gender is either male or female

Comment: then learn it? right now you have dangerous security issues. so just edit your answer with the code and put the ful php script inside your java doesnt matter. what u posted is not complete. as said add error reporting and display errors to your code and you see the syntax problems by youselfes